# Does the task of finding a math proof to a given problem belong to NP?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Just read the following line in algorithms book by Dasgupta, Papadimitrious and Vazerani,

*the task of finding a proof for a given mathematical assertion is a search
problem and is therefore in NP (after all, when a formal proof of a mathematical statement is
written out in excruciating detail, it can be checked mechanically, line by line, by an efficient algorithm).*

I'm not a CS theorist by any stretch, but my understanding is that $NP$ can be informally described as problems with an algorithm $C(I,S)$ where $I$ is the problem statement and $S$ is a solution, such that $C(I,S)$ returns true if $S$ is a solution to $I$ and false otherwise and does so in $O(n^{|I|})$ time.

The statement in the book sounds like they measure efficiency in terms of $O(n^{|S|})$. Yes, given a proof ($S$), I can verify it line by line, but that proof might be exponential in the length of the problem statement ($I$).

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: you may want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_proof_system#IP, which talks about interactive proofs.  PSPACE is considered to be at least as big as NP.